# Restore trashed posts with comments

Tags: comments, trash

When a WordPress post is trashed, all the comments are trashed as well. I would expect the "undo" button to restore both the post and the comments. However, all the comments seem to just disappear : they're not moved into the Dashboard->Comments->Trashed folder, and they are not restored with the original post.

Is there a way to get them back ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate this on a vanilla install.

Comment: I can confirm that @birgire says - this does not happen on a fresh install of 4.6.1 with the twentysixteen theme active. No plugins. Suggestion: try reverting to a default theme to see if that resolves the issue. If not, it's time to play the 'find which plugin is causing this problem' game.

Answer (score 0):

Once you restore the posts that are trashed you can try running the [comment-fix.php](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-category-and-comment-count-after-wordpress-import/) script to reset the comments to appear and show the correct count. If it has been over thirty days in the trash the comments are gone for good, sorry.